# Generating and counting consecutive number as cumsum and second as 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

if we have a dataframe where a column is df.Series = ["a","a","b","c","d","d"] and i want count the consecutive but like the first value should be the cumsum  and second occurrence should be 0 like

```
col["A"] col["B"]            
       a        2
       a        0
       b        1
       c        1
       d        2
```

Comment: please format your input/output as valid python objects or unambiguous text and explicit the logic

Comment: Please workout/edit your question. At least to me, it is not yet clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to add the count of consecutive values as the first row per group, 0 otherwise.

You can use [`groupby`+`transform('size')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get the size per group and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)+[`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to keep only the fist value:

```
# input or use df['colA'] if dataframe
s = pd.Series(["a","a","b","c","d","d"])

# set groups of consecutive values
group = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()

# compute size and keep only first
g = s.groupby(group)
df['colB'] = g.transform('size').mask(g.apply(pd.Series.duplicated), 0)
```

output:

```
0    2
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Create consecutive groups by compare by shifted values:

```
s = pd.Series(["a","a","b","c","d","d"])

g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
print (g)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    4
dtype: int32
```

Andf then mapping value by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with set `0` for duplicates:

```
print (g.map(g.value_counts()))
0    2
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
dtype: int64

out = g.map(g.value_counts()).mask(g.duplicated(), 0)
print (out)
0    2
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    0
dtype: int64
```

Finally for DataFrame use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':s, 'B': out})
print (df)
   A  B
0  a  2
1  a  0
2  b  1
3  c  1
4  d  2
5  d  0
```